# How do I find out the status of a large download from the Mac App Store?

Tags: data-transfer, mac-appstore

I just started downloading OS X Lion, and it's 3.49 GB.

This is the extent of the user interface for the download process:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a place to see the download progress? Can I pause and/or resume the download?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Aha... found it. In the App Store application menu, you can choose **Store** > **Check for Unfinished Downloads** which pops up a window like this:

[image]

Comment: nice! didn't know that was there!

Answer (score 16):

You can also just check the Purchased tab.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can check the size of ~/Library/Application Support/AppStore with Get Info in Finder -- assuming it's Lion that you're downloading, it should be about 3.5GB in total (I'm currently on 444MB, so it will take me a while).